# JS insertBefore pauses video element on iOS

Tags: javascript, css, html, mobile

I happened to figure out why, or at least a theory as to why, it was breaking with my swapNodes function: I think insertBefore creates a copy of the first parameter of insertBefore instead of actually moving it. I noticed this because it seemed that when isHorizontal was true the video didn't break. I changed my JS to the following and it appears to work very well:

```
//works
function swapNodes(node1, node2) {
    if(isHorizontal){
        node1.parentNode.insertBefore(node1,node2);
    }
    else{
        //puts node1 as the last child of parentNode
        //which happens to be under node2.
        node1.parentNode.insertBefore(node1,null);
    }
}
```

I have two divs, one which contains a  tag, I need to swap their orientation based on device orientation, mostly mobile, and my JS code is this:

```
function swapNodes(node1, node2) {
if(isHorizontal){
    node1.parentNode.insertBefore(node1,node2);
}
else{
    node1.parentNode.insertBefore(node2,node1);
}}
```

Works great on desktop but on mobile, I've tested on safari iOS, it causes the video, even in full screen, to reload. Any way around this besides write better css code? I don't want to save the time of the video and wait for the video to reload before setting it to the correct point again as that interrupts the video.

E: Just tried Chrome on my iPhone and it also breaks.

Comment: Please add you HTML and CSS as well.

Comment: @KoshVery added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use `flex` I'd suggest you using CSS property `order` instead of move elements within DOM.

So your code would be simpler:

```js
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', changeOrientation);

function changeOrientation() {
  document.getElementById("row")
    .className = Math.abs(window.orientation) !== 90 ? "rowv" : "rowh";
}
```

```css
.rowh {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.rowv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.columnleft {
  flex: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  order: 0;
}

.columnright {
  flex: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  order: 1;
}

.rowv .columnleft {
  order: 1
}

.rowv .columnright {
  order: 0
}

.underText {
  color: black;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

video {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="row" class="rowh">
  <div id="cleft" class="columnleft">
    <ul id="listFiles">
      <li><a id="sampleli" href="index.html">Loading</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="cright" class="columnright">
    <video id="centeredVid" class="vp" preload="metadata" controls>Your browser does not support the video tag.
  <source id="vsrc" src="http://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_1280x720_60fps_6000k.mp4">
 </video>
    <div class="underText" id="underVid"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and I happened to also figure out why, or at least a theory, it was breaking my way: I think insertBefore creates a copy of the first parameter of insertBefore instead of actually moving it. I changed my JS in main post.